# How to make Maximum values of a stacked raster to form a new raster in R using raster package

Tags: raster, r

I am calculating the Maximum GPP of a year based on a 8-day GPP raster layers. I want to know how to calculate the maximum of the stacked raster at the position of each pixel and to output a new raster. I know Cell statistics in Arcmap can solve this problem,but I have to calculate a lot of data. max() and maxValue() in "raster" package are not worked.

My code is :

```
library(raster)
GPP2000049=raster("GPP.2000049.h23v03.tif") GPP2000057=raster("GPP.2000057.h23v03.tif")
GPP2000065=raster("GPP.2000065.h23v03.tif") GPP2000073=raster("GPP.2000073.h23v03.tif")
GPP2000081=raster("GPP.2000081.h23v03.tif") GPP2000089=raster("GPP.2000089.h23v03.tif")
GPP2000097=raster("GPP.2000097.h23v03.tif") GPP2000105=raster("GPP.2000105.h23v03.tif")
GPP2000113=raster("GPP.2000113.h23v03.tif") GPP2000121=raster("GPP.2000121.h23v03.tif")
GPP2000129=raster("GPP.2000129.h23v03.tif") GPP2000137=raster("GPP.2000137.h23v03.tif")
GPP2000145=raster("GPP.2000145.h23v03.tif") GPP2000153=raster("GPP.2000153.h23v03.tif")
GPP2000161=raster("GPP.2000161.h23v03.tif") GPP2000169=raster("GPP.2000169.h23v03.tif")
GPP2000177=raster("GPP.2000177.h23v03.tif") GPP2000185=raster("GPP.2000185.h23v03.tif")
GPP2000193=raster("GPP.2000193.h23v03.tif") GPP2000201=raster("GPP.2000201.h23v03.tif")
GPP2000209=raster("GPP.2000209.h23v03.tif") GPP2000217=raster("GPP.2000217.h23v03.tif")
GPP2000225=raster("GPP.2000225.h23v03.tif") GPP2000233=raster("GPP.2000233.h23v03.tif")
GPP2000241=raster("GPP.2000241.h23v03.tif") GPP2000249=raster("GPP.2000249.h23v03.tif")
GPP2000257=raster("GPP.2000257.h23v03.tif") GPP2000265=raster("GPP.2000265.h23v03.tif")
GPP2000273=raster("GPP.2000273.h23v03.tif") GPP2000281=raster("GPP.2000281.h23v03.tif")
GPP2000289=raster("GPP.2000289.h23v03.tif") GPP2000297=raster("GPP.2000297.h23v03.tif")
GPP2000305=raster("GPP.2000305.h23v03.tif") GPP2000313=raster("GPP.2000313.h23v03.tif")
GPP2000321=raster("GPP.2000321.h23v03.tif") GPP2000329=raster("GPP.2000329.h23v03.tif")
GPP2000337=raster("GPP.2000337.h23v03.tif") GPP2000345=raster("GPP.2000345.h23v03.tif")
GPP2000353=raster("GPP.2000353.h23v03.tif") GPP2000361=raster("GPP.2000361.h23v03.tif")

MaxGPP2000h23v03=stack(GPP2000049,GPP2000057,GPP2000065,GPP2000073,
                       GPP2000081,GPP2000089,GPP2000097,GPP2000105,
                       GPP2000113,GPP2000121,GPP2000129,GPP2000137,
                       GPP2000145,GPP2000153,GPP2000161,GPP2000169,
                       GPP2000177,GPP2000185,GPP2000193,GPP2000201,
                       GPP2000209,GPP2000217,GPP2000225,GPP2000233,
                       GPP2000241,GPP2000249,GPP2000257,GPP2000265,
                       GPP2000273,GPP2000281,GPP2000289,GPP2000297,
                       GPP2000305,GPP2000313, GPP2000321,GPP2000329,
                       GPP2000337,GPP2000345,GPP2000353,GPP2000361)

MaxGPP2000h23v03=max(MaxGPP2000h23v03)
writeRaster(MaxGPP2000h23v03,filename = "MaxGPP2000h23v03.tif",overwrite=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 6):

You can either use `stackApply` or `calc` to reduce a rasterStack or RasterBrick to the maximum value of each pixel.

```
library(raster)

# Create a test RasterBrick
r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)
r[]=1:ncell(r)
b <- brick(r,r,r,r,r,r)

stackApply(b, indices = rep(1, nlayers(b)), fun = max)

calc(b, function(x){max(x)})
```

Comment: [clusterR](http://www.gis-blog.com/increasing-the-speed-of-raster-processing-with-r-part-23-parallelisation/) can help speed things up for larger files too. Also, for each of calc, stackApply and clusterR, you can make things still more efficient by specifying the output datatype, e.g. if you know your outputs will be whole numbers, its a good idea to specify `datatype='INT2S'`. The raster package creates temp gri/grd files during these operations even when you don't tell it to write to file, so its a good idea to minimise their size where appropriate.

Comment: Thank you so much! It works now. I will have a look at clusterR.

Answer (score 5):

If your stack have `NA` values (or not) use:

```
library(raster)

maxStack <- calc(MaxGPP2000h23v03, function(x) max(x, na.rm = TRUE))
```

or

```
maxStack <- max(MaxGPP2000h23v03, na.rm = TRUE)
```

or

```
maxStack <- stackApply(MaxGPP2000h23v03, indices=rep(1,nlayers(MaxGPP2000h23v03)), fun = max, na.rm=TRUE)
```